# Wrapping return vector<T> on swig

Tags: python, c++, swig

I have a C++ library in which some classes have methods that return `std::vector<T>`, where `T` is a custom class of the library. Is there a way to wrap this outputs to python lists?

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's certainly possible.

C++ classes will have their public interface [wrapped by SWIG](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html#Python_nn20).

And SWIG has [typemaps](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html#Python_nn38) for `std::vector` which can be used like this:

```
%include "typemaps.i"
%include "std_vector.i"
%{ 
#include "MyClass.h"
%}

%template(MyVector) std::vector<MyClass>;
```

Comment: I'm doing what you suggested, but in Python as a return of the mentioned methods I'm seeing the following:
<Swig Object of type 'std::vector< MyClass > *' at 0x7fba76e1d570>swig/python detected a memory leak of type 'std::vector< MyClass > *', no destructor found.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Ok. The error from above was caused by an formatting error on the .i file. Nevetherless, I had to write the actual typemap out in order to recover the lists (actually the returned objects are not python lists, they are "MyVector" type objects, which they behave pretty much as lists) on python. I will post the complete solution. Thank you.